# What is school ''subject'' in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary

Dictionaries give 课，话题，题目，科目，学科。

I'm sure they all have their unique nuances but I want to use ''subject'' in the context of:

My favourite subject is maths. 数学是我最喜欢的___.

I do 8 subjects in school. 我要学习八个___.

Which term is most appropriate here ?

On a related note, what is the formal classifier for subject in my second phrase instead of 个?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 课（also 课程）：a session or a series of sessions on a subject
- 话题：topic
- 题目：a question (on a test paper. Your dictionary probably assumed you meant subject as in title, such as that in an Email.)
- 科目、学科：subject (as a discipline), with 科目 being a bit elementary, and 学科 being more advanced.

So 科目 probably fit your 2 scenarios best.

Related note: 门，as in 八门课程，etc.

Answer (score 1):

Which subjects are you taking at school?
你在学校学那些科目呢？